# How to retrieve nested objects in firebase data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrive data as in the next photo

[image]

and here's what o got from Firebase Documentation

```
mCoursesChild.child("Courses").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              Course temp = data.getValue(Course.class);
            courses.add(temp));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

and "courses" is defined as ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
```

and here's the Course class

```
public class Course {

    private String mCourseName;
    List<Subject> mSubjects;

    public Course(){}       // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Course.class)

    public Course(String CourseName){
        mCourseName = CourseName;
    }

    public String getcourseName(){
        return mCourseName;
    }
    public List<Subject> getSubjects(){ return mSubjects;  }

}
```

Obviously there's something wrong, So what is the value of data.getValue(Course.class) returns ?
Or am I writing the database in a wrong form ?

PS : I'm writing the database objects manually

Comment: You Should avoid the nesting structure in firebase coz in create complexity when data in increase check the Firebase Docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data

Answer (score 3):

I see a few mismatches in your code vs the naming of the JSON properties. Firebase follow JavaBean property naming conventions, which means that this getter:

```
public List<Subject> getSubjects(){ return mSubjects;  }
```

Maps to a property named `subjects`. In your JSON the property is named `Subjects`, which does not match. To fix this problem, either spell `subjects` in your JSON or annotate the getter:

```
@PropertyName("Subjects")
public List<Subject> getSubjects(){ return mSubjects;  }
```

Aside from that, as Anas commented: the Firebase documentation and experts recommend keeping your data structures flat by limiting each branch of your JSON to a single type.

In your case that means I'd recommend keeping three separate top-level lists:

1. Courses
2. Lessons
3. Questions

If you use the same key for the lessons, you still associate the lessons with a course:

```
Courses
  CourseId1
    Name: "Algebra"
Lessons
  CourseId1
    LessonId1
      Name: "Algebra week 1"
```

This will make it much easier to:

- Read only the data you need.
- Ensure users can only access data they're authorized to.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it right, I created the database again with the new levels you mentioned and it worked very well